# Create a geom_bar, and color each bar based on how many times the word is said by each account

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbar, geom-bar

I have a dataframe and I need to create a bar plot of the most frequently used words, using the `ggplot` function. I would like to color each bar based on how many times users say that word.

```
name <- c('Luca', 'Marco','Alberto', 'Luca', 'Marco')
word <- c('pizza', 'cola', 'pizza','cola','pizza')
count <- c(3,5,6,4,1)
total_count <- c (10, 9,10,9,10)
df <- data.frame(name,word,count,total_count)
```

The *count* column indicates how many times the word is said by that person (name). `Total_count` instead indicates how many times the word is said in total (regardless of who says it).

Here's an image as an example of how it should look.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZNQc.png]

Answer (score 0):

`geom_bar` expects un-summarized data similar to the following

```
  name    word 
   <fct>   <fct>
 1 Luca    pizza
 2 Luca    pizza
 3 Luca    pizza
 4 Marco   cola 
 5 Marco   cola 
 6 Marco   cola 
 7 Marco   cola 
 8 Marco   cola 
 9 Alberto pizza
10 Alberto pizza
11 Alberto pizza
12 Alberto pizza
13 Alberto pizza
14 Alberto pizza
15 Luca    cola 
16 Luca    cola 
17 Luca    cola 
18 Luca    cola 
19 Marco   pizza
```

You data is already summarized since it has the `count` column. To create a bar graph from summarized data you can use `geom_col`

```
name <- c('Luca', 'Marco','Alberto', 'Luca', 'Marco')
word <- c('pizza', 'cola', 'pizza','cola','pizza')
count <- c(3,5,6,4,1)
total_count <- c (10, 9,10,9,10)
df <- data.frame(name,word,count,total_count)

ggplot(df, aes(y=word, x=count, fill=name)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: ok thanks, i get it. Now the problem is that I have a dataset with 34k rows(words) and I would like to display only the first 20 rows(words) in the graph. I'm trying but I can't. You can help me? Thanks for your patience

Comment: You need to post a new question for that with example data.